# Exception caught by widgets library 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 543 pos 15: 'children != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-futurebuilder

**My all future builder occure error How can i solve ....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................**

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed assertion: line 543 pos 15: 'children != null': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
FutureBuilder file:///D:/budgram/lib/pages/NotificationsPage.dart:23:16

notificatioons.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context, strTitle: "Notifications..."),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: retrieveNotifications(),
          builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.hasData) {
              circularProgress();
            }
            return ListView(
              children: dataSnapshot.data,
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Please format the question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
circularProgress();
```

needs to be

```
return circularProgress();
```

otherwise the flow will just continue and hit the line with the listview, even if the future has not completed yet.